# How to install ffmpeg on turnkeylinux

Tags: php, installation, ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ in my turnkeylinux. Please guide me how to install and enable it for PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20100210/adding-ffmpeg-lamp) whuich suggests that

```
apt-get install MAKEDEV
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

will do the job

Comment: almost same but a little different apt-get install php5-ffmpeg as given here: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/ (in news section, 2nd news). Please update your answer with this command as well.